# Create a n.2 PHP array from JSON output

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using

```
$data=json_decode($response,true)
```

the output is

```
 array(3) 
{
    ["instrument"]=> string(7) "EUR_USD" ["granularity"]=> string(1) "D" ["candles"]=> array(10) 
    {
        [0]=> array(7) 
        { 
            ["time"]=> string(27) "2016-09-26T21:00:00.000000Z" ["openMid"]=> float(1.125495) ["highMid"]=> float(1.1259) ["lowMid"]=> float(1.119125) ["closeMid"]=> float(1.121605) ["volume"]=> int(17059) ["complete"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
        [1]=> array(7) 
        { 
            ["time"]=> string(27) "2016-09-27T21:00:00.000000Z" ["openMid"]=> float(1.1218) ["highMid"]=> float(1.12369) ["lowMid"]=> float(1.118215) ["closeMid"]=> float(1.12171) ["volume"]=> int(17915) ["complete"]=> bool(true)  
        } 
    } 
}
```

I want to create two arrays with the values openMid and closeMid for example:

```
$open=array(1.125495,1.1218)
$close=array(1.121655,1.12171)
```

I have to develop the foreach code in order to achieve that.
Anyone can help me?  Thanks

Comment: Can I see the real array itself

Comment: hi this  is the json output:{ "instrument" : "EUR_USD", "granularity" : "D", "candles" : [ { "time" : "2016-10-06T21:00:00.000000Z", "openMid" : 1.115185, "highMid" : 1.12049, "lowMid" : 1.110455, "closeMid" : 1.12013, "volume" : 43707, "complete" : true }, { "time" : "2016-10-09T21:00:00.000000Z", "openMid" : 1.11794, "highMid" : 1.120455, "lowMid" : 1.115675, "closeMid" : 1.116005, "volume" : 11271, "complete" : false } ] }

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution below:

```
$open= [];              //Declare empty array to hold openMid values
$close= [];             //Declare empty array to hold closeMid values

#Loop through $array 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    #If any of the value is an array
    if (is_array($value)) { 
        $arr= $value;       //Store the array
    }
}

//Loop through the second array
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    //If the value is of index openMid
    if ($val->openMid) {
        $open[]= $val->openMid;     //Push into the $open array holder
    }

    //If the value is of index closeMid
    if ($val->closeMid) {
        $close[]= $val->closeMid;   //Push into the $close array holder
    }
}
```